# Is it possible to finish async.js loop early?

Tags: javascript, async.js

I am looking for a way to finish async.js loop early before all the callbacks get called. Is there any built-in function to do so? If not, is there any way around to achieve the desired functionality?

```
async.forEachOf(children, function(child, i, cb){

    if (condition == true) {

        // finish early - call cb() for all iterations

    }

    cb()

}, function(err){


})
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423462/is-there-a-way-to-stop-execution-of-next-function-of-series-with-async-in-nodejs

Comment: You can make an async JS for loop yourself if you want the functionality, do you need a fiddle example on how to?

Comment: It would be much appreciated if you help me with a fiddle example.

Comment: Not currently but see https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/1064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you should pass a error parameter into your callback function like this:

```
async.forEachOf(children, function(child, i, cb){
    ....
    cb(condition)
}, function(err){
   // Error handling
})
```

If condition is True the loop will stop.

[async.forEachOf documentation](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachOf)